# Module submission guideline - configuration storage

Tags: 7, multi-sites, domain-access

I am trying to finish and submit my first module project. It's a QA/tab launcher thing that is meant for multisites. Basically, I am using a few different methods to retrieve a list of sites that are part of the same multisite as the site that the module is enabled on. The piece I have a question about is a configuration page that saves a list, from that list, of "enabled" sites.

**Here is my problem:** I want a multisite-wide configuration, but I am concerned about how i'm doing it. I understand that the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module would provide more than enough functionality for cross-site database access and would probably be more up to the Drupal guidelines, but it's extremely overkill! Domain Access will scare off people that don't want to configure each settings.php file, etc.

All I need, literally, is to save 2 non-associative arrays in a way that each multisite has access. My current setup saves them in the public files directory as 2 .csv files, and works as well as I know how to code it; as far as saving .csv's and retrieving the rows go, I think i'm doing it right. It doesn't really have performance issues tied to it because it truly is a lightweight piece; the only reason i'm doing it this way is for global access.

**My question is:** is this going to get flagged as non-conformant to the Drupal way because i'm not saving it in a table? I don't see anything in the guides specifically guiding me away from doing it that way... but it's just a guess that they won't like it.

Comment: I'm confused. Domain Access is for single-site (with multiple faces), and all the rest of your post is about multisite. Also, Domain Access will not "scare off people that don't want to configure each settings.php file" - multisite requires that, DA does not. So what's your module about?

Comment: Ah, I must have misunderstood the purpose of the Domain Access module... oops. I just realized I can give a link to the GitHub repo - https://github.com/taytayevanson/multisite_launcher. It's for launching the same parameter string across multiple sites, I built it at and for my job in a module that's not really able to be used by the community. The JS is the secret sauce; browsers don't normally let you launch a bunch of tabs. The JS isn't in the repo yet... but that's the idea!

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is to submit your sandbox to Drupal.org Project Applications, and see what people say.  Its fairly rare to get an outright rejection.  People will inspect your code, offer suggestions for improvement, etc.  Better to get started ASAP.

As for your specific issue:  I think the way you are going about it is not in accordance with The Drupal Way ™.  Your best bet would probably be to generate a PHP file, only allowing your module to access this sort of administrative control from the site in Default.

Comment: Make sure to run your sandbox through pareview.sh.

Comment: Sorry, circling back... I am going to upload my project  ASAP, but can I ask some specifics on what I should have this PHP file do to have this module be more in accordance? How would I set up this globally accessible PHP file to contain or reference configuration?